# Problems installing VMware on arch linux

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, arch-linux, vmware-workstation, linux-kernel

I'm trying to install VMware but when it gets to "before you can run VMware, several modules must be compiled and loaded into the running kernel" I click install, enter my password, and i get a error

```
Unable to stop services.

See log file /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-28896.log for details.
```

hoping to find a solution i tried looking for that using nano and the file didnt exist, i looked in the folder while i ran vmware and no logfile was created for this, im not sure what i need todo and it's very vague. i looked online and at forums but i cannot find anyone with anything close to my issue

my kernel BTW

```
4.2.3-1-ARCH
```

I just tried to use VMware patcher to fix it, with -v too, and I get an error while running it

```
==> Patching VMware Workstation Pro v12.0.0 for kernel 4.2.3-1-ARCH..
-> [vmci]
-> Extracting archives..
-> Patching..
patching file vmci-only/linux/driver.c
patching file vmci-only/linux/vmciKernelIf.c
patching file vmci-only/shared/vm_device_version.h
-> Recreating archives..
==> Installing modules..
sh: /home/hashfastr/vmware: Is a directory
Unable to stop services
==> error: Unable to build. See:
* /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-1360.log
* /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-17013.log
* /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-17148.log
* /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-18919.log
* /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-18925.log
* /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-18931.log
* /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-19162.log
* /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-19492.log
* /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-19769.log
* /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-20058.log
* /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-20336.log
* /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-2069.log
* /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-2075.log
* /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-2081.log
* /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-21046.log
* /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-21323.log
* /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-21405.log
* /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-21998.log
```

Comment: Did you try to compile the missing modules as sudo or as a regular user? `Unable to stop services` seems the typical error message that comes when you are not  a priviledged user.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae just uninstalled and reinstalled using sudo, same error

Comment: @MariusMatutiae

Comment: @MariusMatutiae just found this error in the install: 

Extracting VMware Installer...done.

(vmware-installer.py:16308): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(vmware-installer.py:16308): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:1163: error: unexpected identifier `direction', expected character `}'
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Getting VMWare to build its modules in Arch is always tricky because the kernel is always newer than VMWare's supported version.

I'd suggest installing [vmware-patch](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/vmware-patch/) from the AUR.

`vmware-patch` will automatically patch and build the vmware-modules when you install it.

You should then re-run it every time you upgrade either VMWare or the kernel.

```
sudo vmware-patch
```

It ought to be able to stop/start the VMWare services automatically, but if you do get the same failure then at least you'll have it in a terminal window where you can see it better.

Comment: i did as told and got this error

Comment: ==> Patching VMware Workstation Pro v12.0.0 for kernel 4.2.3-1-ARCH..
  -> [vmci]
==> Installing modules..
==> error: Unable to build. Re-run with '-v' (--verbose) or see

Comment: * /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-1360.log
    * /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-17013.log
    * /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-17148.log
    * /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-18919.log
    * /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-18925.log
    * /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-18931.log
    * /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-19162.log
    * /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-19492.log
    * /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-19769.log
    * /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-20058.log
    * /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-20336.log
    * /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-2069.log
    * /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-2075.log
    * /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-2081.log

Comment: You should probably rerun with -v, and if that doesn't enlighten you, edit your post to add the new information.

Comment: i did and still the same error practically with a extra few lines

Comment: ==> Patching VMware Workstation Pro v12.0.0 for kernel 4.2.3-1-ARCH..
  -> [vmci]
    -> Extracting archives..
    -> Patching..
patching file vmci-only/linux/driver.c
patching file vmci-only/linux/vmciKernelIf.c
patching file vmci-only/shared/vm_device_version.h
    -> Recreating archives..
==> Installing modules..
sh: /home/hashfastr/vmware: Is a directory
Unable to stop services
==> error: Unable to build. See: